# Modelos en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

tengo un problemita para llamar un modelo?
los modelos los guardo por ejemplo /model/ventas/ventasmodel pero para llamarlos desde una linea por ejemplo
$totalventas=$this->VentasModel->totaldia($hoy);//

no me siver ya que consultaria en la carpeta donde esta que seria models/inicio/ y no en models/ventas/, existiria alguna forma o directamente me conviene cargar el modelo con un constructor?

Comment: No solicites ejemplos, ya que [es.so] ni es un repositorio de código, ni es un sitio de tutoriales. Delimita tu pregunta a un problema _en específico_. No olvides además especificar en el título cuál es el problema en cuestión. Lee [ask].

Comment: ah ok, recibido